# How do I make CSS grids fill empty space between rows of items without resorting to Flex Boxes?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

When I list a bunch of items, but not enough to fill the div, I get ugly spaces in between rows.  Is there a way to get rid of this spacing?  I've tried using grid-auto-flow but it doesn't seem to work either.  I'm not too proficient at CSS/SASS, but I speculate that it's my lack of specifying `grid-template-rows`, but I could be mistaken.  In any case, here's what I have so far:

```
.Playlists {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(120px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Just an FYI, I don't want to use flex boxes here because I do not like how they handle item wrapping.

The ugly no no when there aren't enough items to fill the div:

[image: Picture when there aren't enough items to fill parent container]

The beautiful yes yes when there are enough items to fill the div:

[image: Picture when there are enough items to fill parent container]

Comment: between your *no* and *yes* there is simply more elements. CSS cannot add more element for you

Comment: ^ or you are looking for `align-content:start`

Comment: ^ worked!  Post and i'll accept it as a solution :)